# Pandas extract certain part of cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following strings in the column of dataframe df

| mix |
| --- |
| [84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33] |
| [ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32] |

I want to add column id, name and age to dataframe as below

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | max | 33 |
| 21 | kris | 32 |

I tried

```
df.id = df.mix.str.extract('(id=.*(?=,))')
```

but that does not work

Comment: What is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: why do I only see a Lots of `W`s in the title and main body of the question? Is that a bug?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3):

if the string format is fixed, then simply use `str.extact`

```
data = {'mix': {0: '84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33', 
                1: '[ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]',
                # 2: 'id=23,age=20'
               }}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfn = df['mix'].str.extract('id=(\d+),name=(\w+),age=(\d+)')
dfn.columns = ['id', 'name', 'age']
df_result = pd.concat([df, dfn], axis=1)

print(df_result)

#                                     mix  id  name age
#     0      84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33  22   max  33
#     1  [ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]  21  kris  32
```

---

if the column is not fix, then use `str.extractall`:

```py
data = {'mix': {0: '84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33', 
                1: '[ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]',
                2: 'id=23,age=20'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = ['id', 'name', 'age']
cols_str = "|".join(cols)
print(cols_str)

dfn = (df['mix'].str.extractall(f'({cols_str})=(\w+)')
       .droplevel(1)
       .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
       .unstack()
       .assign(mix=df['mix']))
print(dfn)

id|name|age
0 age  id  name                                mix
0  33  22   max      84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33
1  32  21  kris  [ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]
2  20  23   NaN                       id=23,age=20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
>>> cols = ['id', 'name', 'age']
>>> ( df.mix.str.extractall(r'=(.*?)(?:,|])')
        .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename(columns=lambda x:cols[x]) )
match  id  name age
0      22   max  33
1      21  kris  32
```

If you want `mix` column as well:

```
>>> ( df.mix.str.extractall(r'=(.*?)(?:,|])')
        .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename(columns=lambda x:cols[x])
        .assign(mix=df.mix) )

match  id  name age                                mix
0      22   max  33    [84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33]
1      21  kris  32  [ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionaries and convert to `Series`, so last is created new DataFrame with columns names by values before `=`, for `id` is created column if `id` is substring:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mix': {0: '84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33', 
                           1: '[ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]'}})
print (df)
                                 mix
0      84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33
1  [ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]

def f(x):
    d = {}
    for y in x.strip('[]').split(','):
        a, b = y.split('=')
        if 'id' in a:
            d['id'] = b
        else:
            d[a] = b
    return pd.Series(d)
                
df = df.mix.apply(f)
print (df)
   id  name age
0  22   max  33
1  21  kris  32
```

If possible some `=` is missing:

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    for y in x.strip('[]').split(','):
        if '=' in y:
            a, b = y.split('=')
            if 'id' in a:
                d['id'] = b
            else:
                d[a] = b
    return pd.Series(d)
                
df = df.mix.apply(f)
print (df)
   id  name age
0  22   max  33
1  21  kris  32
```

For original columns use:

```
df1 = df.join(df.mix.apply(f))
print (df1)
                                 mix  id  name age
0      84726gsdid=22,name=max,age=33  22   max  33
5  [ieiuf8382id=21,name=kris,age=32]  21  kris  32
```

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Jerr567 - Can you test now?

Comment: What if I want to keep previous colunm?

Comment: @Jerr567 - then use `df = df.join(df.mix.apply(f))`